# Any way to have document read time in SP library Tile View JSON Format

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

Is there any way to estimate the document read time in SP Document library Tile view using JSON formatting.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**.

This is not possible using JSON formatting capabilities of SharePoint online.

**Documentation**:

1. [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)
2. [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)

Comment: I want to get URL from the Hyperlink column in the JSON Formatter, I am using [$ImageURL.Url] but can't getting the value from this. any Idea to how to get this url?

Comment: No need to append `.Url`. Ask a new question & I will explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Per my research, you are unable to estimate the document read time using JSON formatting.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting

In addition, there is an OOB feature called **Inside look**, which provides a peek into documents with an estimated time to read the document and the author’s key points.
[image]

Note:This feature is available exclusively on Word documents written in English.

More information for your reference:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/see-file-insights-before-you-open-a-file-87a23bbc-a516-42e2-a7b6-0ecb8259e026